# through textbox loop string join in textboxes

Tags: vb.net

simple, I want to display its values ​​i in the textbox but on the same line separated by a comma. that is, my textbox should be Textbox1.Text = `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` so how do i do that in a simpler form without writing many lines.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < 9
    i = i + 1
    TextBox1.AppendText(i & "," & vbNewLine)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, vbLf)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(startNumber, Length)` gives you the numbers and `String.Join` adds the numbers to a string separated the a comma.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 9))
End Sub
```